# Java: "lossy conversion" when trying to return lowest value from an array

Tags: arrays, function

I'm trying to figure out how to return the lowest value in the rainfall array, keep getting this error. I made counter a double since at one point I was trying to just return the counter variable.. didn't work either. Any/all help is appreciated!

```
public static double determineLow(double[] rainfall)
  {
    double lowest;
    double counter; 
    lowest = rainfall[0];
    for (counter = 0; counter < rainfall.length; counter++)
    {
      if (rainfall[counter] < lowest)        //error here
        lowest = rainfall[counter];          //as well as here
    }
    return lowest;
  }
```

Comment: I am confused as to how this code even compiles? you're missing type definitions for the counter and lowest variables

Comment: @psrcek What do you mean? Didn't I do that at the top of the function

Comment: wait nevermind, i'm just a derp, your code is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rainfall` is an array (of `double` in this case but that doesn't matter, could be any type) and you are using `counter` to reference elements in it. `counter` is your index and can not be of type `double`. The index has to be of type `int` (or smaller like `short` or `byte`).

Change to:

```
int counter;
```

Or even better, since you do not need the variable outside of your for you can have it like:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < rainfall.length; counter++) {
   if (rainfall[counter] < lowest)
        lowest = rainfall[counter];
}
```

If you think about it, you don't really need that index anywhere you just need to iterate over all the numbers so in java you can do the same like this

```
for (double aNumberInRainfall : rainfall) {
    if (aNumberInRainfall < lowest)
        lowest = aNumberInRainfall;
}
```